# Unable to add spaces

Tags: linux, python, shell-script, sed, perl

How can i add spaces between my outputs using sed/echo or any other command in linux?

Preferred Output:

```
Virtual Machine  Test01 status  Running.
Virtual Disk  Test01 size  61GB
Physical Disk  HITACHI (170)
Physical Disk  HITACHI (171)
Physical Disk  HITACHI (172)   

Virtual Machine  Test02 status  Running.
Virtual Disk  Test02 size  61GB
Physical Disk  HITACHI (163)
Physical Disk  HITACHI (164)
Physical Disk  HITACHI (165)
Physical Disk  HITACHI (173)

Virtual Machine  Test03 status  Running.
Virtual Disk Test03_DISK1 (33) size  61GB
Physical Disk  HITACHI (137)
Physical Disk  HITACHI (138)
```

My script o/p:

```
cat /tmp/test.txt | while read in; do echo -en '\n';  ./ovm_vmdisks -u admin -p xxxxxx -h localhost -v "$in"; done |  sed "s/'//g" | egrep -i "Virtual Machine|Virtual Disk|Physical Disk" |sed "s/://g" > /tmp/Automated/Virtualmachines_DETAILS.txt; cat /tmp/Automated/Virtualmachines_DETAILS.txt

Virtual Machine  Test01 status  Running.
Virtual Disk  Test01 size  61GB
Physical Disk  HITACHI (170)
Physical Disk  HITACHI (171)
Physical Disk  HITACHI (172)    <<<< My First output ends here and right after this i would need spaces
Virtual Machine  Test02 status  Running.
Virtual Disk  Test02 size  61GB
Physical Disk  HITACHI (163)
Physical Disk  HITACHI (164)
Physical Disk  HITACHI (165)
Physical Disk  HITACHI (173)  <<<< Second one and so on
Virtual Machine  Test03 status  Running.
Virtual Disk Test03_DISK1 (33) size  61GB
Physical Disk  HITACHI (137)
Physical Disk  HITACHI (138)
```

Comment: have to tried just writing a newline, `\n`?

Comment: I tried it but that didn't helped..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed '2,$s/^Virtual Machine/\n&/' file
```

Comment: Sed always steals the show..Thanks a lot Cyrus. It worked!!

Comment: Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Write and empty echo where you want that newline

For example

```
echo Foo
echo
echo Bar
```

Results in...

```
Foo

Bar
```